# Sitecore e-commerce new payment provider

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, sitecore

I'm having an issue with sitecore e-commerce since I'm very new to it ,I couldn't find any clear steps or code snippet about how to implement a new payment provider , I know that the Authorize.net is already implemented but I need to add PayFlow Pro payment provider , do I have to do new code changes ?if yes what are they ? please help

Answer (score 1):

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/sefe/sefe101/sefe_developers_cookbook-a4.pdf
Page 26 will help you :)

Comment: actually I did see this document and it didn't help

Comment: When you explain what you need, we might be able to help you :)

Comment: I don't know if I am asking the right question or not ? How to create a new payment provider for "PayFlow Pro" using the E-commerce module ? I tried the documentation it was not so clear there was only a small paragraph that was talking about the online payment provider and it wasn't enough , thanks for being patient with me  :)

Answer (score 0):

The [SEFE 1.1 Payment Method Reference Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/sefe/sefe110/sefe_payment_method_reference_guide_11-usletter.pdf) provides details for "Implementing a New Payment Provider", including how to register it with Unity and step by step code samples for implementing the Sitecore.Ecommerce.DomainModel.Payments.IOnlinePaymentProvider interface.

Otherwise I've taken to ripping [the provided SEFE Payment Providers](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/SEFE/SEFE11/Module_Updates/102_101227_to_110_110511.aspx) apart using something like ILSpy or Reflector.

Answer (score 0):

I've just blogged about how to create an on-site payment provider, but the steps I show could be used for an off-site payment provider with a little tweaking.

http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/sefe-on-site-payment-provider/